# having difficulty to execute powershell from command prompt

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

Unable to execute powershell script from the command prompt.
test.ps1 file:

```
echo "testing"
```

Here is the error:

> c:\run>powershell .\test.ps1 echo : The term 'Write-Output' is not
> recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
> program. out-lineoutput : Win32 internal error "Access is denied" 0x5
> occurred while reading the console output buffer. Contact Microsoft
> Customer Support Services.
> + CategoryInfo          : ReadError: (:) [out-lineoutput], HostException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ReadConsoleOutput,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutLineOutputCommand
>
> c:\run>

The command prompt is at "Administrator".

The path is set ok:

```
echo %PATH% at the prompt
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
```

Get-ExecutionPolicy -List

```
        Scope ExecutionPolicy
        ----- ---------------
MachinePolicy    Unrestricted
   UserPolicy       Undefined
      Process       Undefined
  CurrentUser    Unrestricted
 LocalMachine       Undefined
```

Comment: It almost looks like powershell.exe is confused about which console is hosting it. How are you accessing this machine and invoking cmd? Physical screen, RDP, PSRP, SSH?

Comment: I am accessing the machine using RDP.